# Construct a smooth function satisfying certain conditions

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functions

I need to construct a smooth $C^{\infty}$ real function $f(x)$ such that

$$f(x)=0\quad x<-1$$ and $$f(x)=1 \quad x>1$$ and $$0\le f(x)\le 1 \quad \forall x$$

I know I can construct the following function: $$g(x)=\frac{\int_\infty^x dt\ \theta(t+1)\theta(1-t) \exp\left({-\frac{1}{(x+1)^2}- \frac{1}{(x-1)^2}}\right)}{\int_\infty^\infty dt\ \theta(t+1)\theta(1-t) \exp\left({-\frac{1}{(x+1)^2}- \frac{1}{(x-1)^2}}\right)} $$

where $\theta(x)$ is the [Heaviside step function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function)

But I want a more explicit function. A piecewise defined function is OK, as long as each piece has a nice "explicit" formula.

Comment: What is this $\theta?$

Comment: @zhw. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function

Comment: Is your $g(x)$ smooth in the $C^{\infty}$ sense?

Comment: @Andreas Yes, because the integrand is a $C^{\infty}$ function. The integral of a $C^{\infty}$ function should also be $C^{\infty}$

Comment: the arctan answer seems the nicest. I wanted to point out that exp(-1/x) has value and all derivatives 0 at 0 on the right. A function with value and all derivatives 0, multiplied by any smooth function will also have that. Thus exp(-1/(x+1)-1/(1-x)) will have value and all derivatives 0 at -1 on the right and at +1 on the left. So we can extend it smoothly with 0 on the left and on the right of the interval [-1,+1]. If we integrate this from -1 to x, this function is a smooth step function,which you can scale and shift to the request. ie you dont need to square 1/(x+1) and 1/(1-x).

Comment: the million dollar question is whether there is a nice formula for the integral of exp(-1/x - 1/(1-x)) from -1 to x. Have tried without luck, probably there isnt. I tried simpler problem of integrating exp(-1/x) by assuming it was a power series in 1/x times exp(-1/x), but that led to a divergent power series as solution! exp(-1/x) is unusual in that value and all derivatives are 0, so the taylor series isnt equal to the function on the right!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this has a good chance of working:

$$f(x)=\begin{cases} \dfrac{1}{2}+\dfrac{1}{\pi}\arctan (te^{1/(1-t^2)}) & |t|<1\\1& t\ge 1\\0 & t\le 1\end{cases}$$

I haven't checked all the details yet.

Comment: @user34669 I changed my answer.

Comment: I've checked, it's right. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In $-1\le x\le 1$ define $$f(x) = \frac{1+ \sin(\pi x /2)}{2}$$.
Otherwise define as in your question, $$f(x)=0\quad x<-1$$ and $$f(x)=1 \quad x>1$$.

This is "smooth" in the sense that it is continuous and the first derivatives are also continuous.

EDIT:
sorry, the "$C^{\infty}$-smoothness" was edited into the OP's question *after* I posted my answer.

Comment: This doesn't address the question.

Comment: The 2nd derivative of $f(x)$ at $x=-1$ is not continuous.

Comment: Thanks, I want a $C^{\infty}$ function

Comment: smooth is maths jargon to mean infinitely differentiable! you are confusing visually smooth with maths smooth! But you need to have done pure maths at uni to know this maths jargon! Your function is only smooth on each side of -1, +1, but isnt smooth at those points.